# Applying DeMorgan's Law to Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've applied DeMorgan's Law before but I'm not sure how DeMorgan's Law works specifically with conditional probabilities. Suppose I have a conditional probability on events compliment of W, compliment of X, and compliment of Y, given Z where W, X, and Y are mutually exclusive as follows:

$$
P(W^{C}X^{C}Y^{C}|Z)=1-P(W^{C}X^{C}Y^{C}| Z)^{C}
$$

I then apply DeMorgan's Law and I think I get this:

$$
1-P(W\cup X\cup Y\cup Z|A)
$$
$$
1-(P(W|A)+P(X|A)+P(Y|A))
$$
Could someone tell me if DeMorgan's Law can be applied to a conditional probability like this or if I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The law $\def\P{\mathbb P}$$\P(A^c) = 1 - \P(A)$ holds for all probiability measures, hence also for $\P = P(\cdot\mid Z)$, that is we have 
$$ P(A^c \mid Z) = 1 - P(A \mid Z)$$ 
for all events $A$.

In your example, what exactly is $A$? What you can do, is 
$$ P(W^c\cap X^c \cap Y^c \mid Z) = 1 - P\bigl((W^c \cap X^c \cap Y^c)^c \mid Z\bigr)$$
hence as $W$, $X$ and $Z$ are disjoint, 
$$  = 1 - P(W \cup X \cup Y \mid Z) = 1 - P(W \mid Z) - P(X \mid Z) - P(Y \mid Z)$$

Comment: Thank you, that explains it perfectly!